# How to handle versioning of htaccess file?

Tags: git, .htaccess, svn, versioning

I'm using git to develop a project and each machine may need a slightly different `.htaccess` file. I wonder if there's any technique to handle versioning this file without having a separate one on each machine?

Basically I have something like that in mind (pseudo-code):

```
<MachineX>
    RewriteBase /somepath/ 
</MachineX>

<MachineY>
    RewriteBase /anotherpath/ 
</MachineY>

<Production>
    RewriteBase /prodpath/ 
</Production>
```

Basically, each machine can have their custom code in .htaccess if needed. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to have a template `.htaccess` file in your main branch, say `master`.

Then you create a branch from `master` for each machine and commit modifications to this file on this specific branch.

And when you want to integrate changes from `master` into that branch, just switch to it and merge with `master`.

Comment: You'd have to be sure not to commit changes while a "sub"-branch is checked out, or you could end up with a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways at least

1. Common-style: using branches (branch per target, branched the whole project, not single file)
2. Smudge/clean filters: Some $VARIABLE on place of mutable strings have to be replaced (by linked scripts) by real rarget-specific code on checkout and converted back to common-string on commit